# reload data fail within tableviewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

```
class SelectionBoxViewController: UITableViewController,UISearchBarDelegate {
    var searchbar = UISearchBar()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchbar.delegate = self
    }

    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {   
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

It crashed at `tableView.reloadData()` with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Comment: post the stacktrace of the crash so we can understand what's causing the crash

Comment: where can i find the stack trace of the crashh

Answer (score 0):

It could be either 2 things (Inclusive):

- You didn't link the class to a tableView in the storyboard
- The required delegates for the UITableViewDataSource are not implemented

Try adding this function to your class:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 0
}
```

And this one:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Comment: Note that it is a UITableViewController, those bullets should be exist by default.

Comment: Ahmad is right. i just not place all of the code here